# Retrieve Application ProductName whilst in an installer

Tags: c#, installation

I have an installer class for my program (that resides within the application project). I also have a class that dictates where my data save locations are which uses `Application.ProductName` obviously whilst in the installer this does not come back as my product name but it comes back as something like `Windows Installer - Unicode` which is expected.

How do I then, in the installer class, retrieve the actual product name? Would I have to hardcode it or can I tweak my installer class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass data to your custom action (i.e. installer class) in setup project using [CustomActionData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w2fhwzz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property. Now installer class can access them via [Context.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installcontext.parameters.aspx). For your requirement, you can pass product name as some parameter - for example, CustomActionData value could be `/prodName="[ProductName]"` and then access it via `Context.Parameters["prodName"]`. The special syntax `[property name]` is used to pass various installer properties (to custom action) - see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905.aspx#product_information_properties) for various pre-define properties available. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) will help in understanding how to pass custom data.

Answer (score 0):

### `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name`

You can get the application name inside the installer class using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name`, If you also want to get the user-selected directory for installation. You can do that with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.